# Need regular expression help for stripping the string from format xxxxxx/x/xxxxx/xxx

Tags: java, regex

Hi there is a requirement to strip a string along `backslash`(/)

For example I have

```
String vret = "Comment Four/Y/34147/D_Z";
```

This has to be splitted into 4 string  namely

```
Str sarr[]={comment,Y,34147,D_Z}
```

The string will be always in this format only like `XXXXX/X/XXXXXX/XXX`:

- the first part will be alphanumeric value,
- the second part is single character
- the third is always a number
- the fourth is any character

I am assuming there will be regex to do this kind of operations in java

Comment: Did you forget the quotes around this string, or does the string actually start with `"String vret = ..."`? Why not simply split along slashes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about

```
 String[] sarr = vret.split("/");
```

[Oracle](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) even has the documentation.

Comment: Downvote?? It's a correct answer. It's the accepted answer and I even provided a link to the documentation for the OP to inform himself further. Please tell me what I did wrong to deserve a downvote?

Answer (score 1):

using full regex and pre-compiled pattern

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([\\w]+)/(\\w)/(\\d+)/(\\.*)");

Matcher m = p.matcher(vret);

if(m.matches()){
    String first = m.group(1);
    String second= m.group(2);
    int third = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3));
    String fourth= m.group(4);

}
```

Comment: Would need to allow for whitespace in the first group.

Answer (score 1):

`String sarr[] = vret.split("/");`
Simple, uh ?